# How do I get Linkedin's avatars from an email address

Tags: php, linkedin-api, avatar

Apps like Xobni show the linkedin avatar from a user when they only have the email address to go bye. I can't find a way to use linkedin's API to get the avatar by searching on an email address ( https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api ). Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure Xobni doesn't use a service like Gravatar?

Comment: Yes, it has photos for people not on gravatar and the photos even have little linkedin icons on the bottom right of them.

Comment: Seems this is not possible; Xobni appears to have a relationship with linkedin/facebook so are probably paying for this ability. http://www.quora.com/How-does-Xobni-associate-Facebook-and-LinkedIn-Data-with-user-email-addresses?q=How+does+xobni+show+linkedin

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields see picture-url.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. The problem is to use the profile-fields you need the userid of the linkedin user. I am not sure how I get that from the email address. https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api does not mention it, nor does https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api

Comment: actually about a third of the way down the people-search page it gives you the way to receive a profile image:    http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,headline),num-results)

Comment: Hi shortsick, thanks - but that requires you have the id for the person. I don't have that; I only have their email address. I can't see how I get the details that xobni manages to get (just the public data obviously, from the email address).